# Relation.all deprecation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

If I do the following in Rails 3:

```
users=User.where("last_name like ?","s%").all
```

It returns an array and I can immediately treat it as an array by doing something like the following:

```
users.unshift(User.new)
```

In Rails 4 the .all statement gives the deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to
>   eager-load a relation, you can call #load

So now .all is returning a relation and presumably the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
users=User.where("last_name like ?","s%").all

users=User.where("last_name like ?","s%")
```

In other words the variable 'users' is now a Relation rather than an array.

My question is what magic is going on to enable the Relation to be treated as an array because the 'users.unshift' statement still works on the Relation and turns it into an Array. Is it forcing a load of the relation?

Should I really be using a '.load'. It does not seem to be required but logically it should be.

Comment: `ActiveRecord` collections act like arrays, so you can call any array methods on them (although they will turn it into an array so you'll lose the special `ActiveRecord` methods). You don't have to call `#load` to have it act like an array. Just pretend that the `ActiveRecord` collection is an array and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` uses `method_missing` to delegate most array methods to `Array`. unshift is one those that.

See the source here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1361b676d3a51aa0fca299f432e75032dd29a9d9/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L128

```
def array_delegable?(method)
  Array.method_defined?(method) && BLACKLISTED_ARRAY_METHODS.exclude?(method)
end

def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if @klass.respond_to?(method)
    scoping { @klass.public_send(method, *args, &block) }
  elsif array_delegable?(method)
    to_a.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  elsif arel.respond_to?(method)
    arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

See [ptd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3945932/ptd)'s comment

> `ActiveRecord` collections act like arrays, so you can call any array
>   methods on them (although they will turn it into an array so you'll
>   lose the special `ActiveRecord` methods). You don't have to call `#load`
>   to have it act like an array. Just pretend that the `ActiveRecord`
>   collection is an array and you'll be fine